# jquery .done return value - confused

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to build small functions that do very specific things and use them on handlers.
I was trying to do this sending JSON objects to a php script that then returns responses in form of json objects.

This is the function I wrote so far:

```
function isRegistered(courseObj){
    var posting = $.post("is-user-registered.php", courseObj);
    posting.done(function(data){
        var res = $.parseJSON(data);
        if(res.response == "success"){
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    });
}
```

This is the handler:

```
$('a.button.findDelegate').bind("click", function(){
    var textToSearch = $('#findUserBox').val();
    var txtObj = {};
    var courseObj = {};

    courseObj['courseId'] = $('input[name=courseId]').val();
    courseObj['email'] = txtObj['text'] = textToSearch;

    if(txtObj['text'].length > 2){
        if(isRegistered(courseObj) === 0){
            console.log("search user and then add it to the list");
        } else {
                            console.log("this user is already registered lets throw an error");
                    }
    }
    return false;
});
```

The problem is that `isRegistered` always returns undefined.
I am almost certain this has something to do with the .done not being executed straight away since on chrome `undefined` is actually being logged before the ajax call.

If that's the case how can I force the handler to wait for the `isRegistered` response?

I am open to all suggestions, I am probably using the wrong tool (jQuery) to do this?

Sorry about the lack of clarity.

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous by default, you need to use callback function of request and code your logic according this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: I added the more in-depth answer to your problem. Does my answer help you or should I delete it/

Comment: Your answer is absolutely fine you do not need to delete it, it can help other users that are facing the same problem so I think it is valid.

I am not 100% happy to do it that way though since it causes (in my opinion) endless callbacks that look messy and unmaintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`done` as all async callbacks return sometime in the future, maybe in 1ms and maybe in 10min, (and some callbacks will never fire like `error\success`).

It means you can use the values only inside the callback.

Try changing the code to something like:

```
function isRegistered(courseObj){
    var posting = $.post("is-user-registered.php", courseObj);
    posting.done(function(data){
        var res = $.parseJSON(data);
        if(res.response == "success"){
            // Do what's needed here ------------------------------
        } else {
            // Do what's needed here ------------------------------
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I understand this but it means I have to get functions to do more than they need to.

Take this code for instance:
    //handler 1
    if(isRegistered() === true){
       deleteUser();
    }

    //handler 2
    if(isRegistered() === true){
       editUser();
    }

if I put the code inside that function that needs to do something very specific then I won't be able to reuse that function very easily :(

Comment: @AngeloMoreira, You can use `if(res.response == "success"){ DoSomething();}...`